# Android project cannot recognize a class from extenal library

Tags: java, android

I have an Android project and a web application project.
I want to send an Object between them.  I opened a new project with a class called SharedObj.
this class I exported to a jar file and I imported it to both project as external library's.
In the web application project it's recognized the class SharedObj and in the android project it's not.

what is the problem?

Comment: have you placed it in the libs folder?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem weeks ago. I created "libs" folder and placed the *.jar there with other external. It works for me.

Comment: btw, every time you make changes on the SharedObj you will have to create the jar again and overwrite on libs folder. It is very annoying, but it seems to be the only way, since no Java project import is possible.

Comment: right click on project -> Build path -> Configure Build Path -> "Libraries" tab -> Add Jar. Then browse to your project, search libs folder and select the *.jar

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suspect you put your jar into the wrong folder. The jar should go into the /libs folder, at the top level of your project directory.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows..

Copy your jar file by doing **right click -> copy**, then open eclipse and **paste it in the libs** folder. Then right click on the pasted file and click on **Build Path -> Add to build path**